# Adding background image in vim

Tags: vim

Is their any way to add background image in VIM.
like,

> :set background=dark

I don't know is is possible or not. If you know any way to do this tell me.
Thanks.....

Comment: If you have 256 colour terminal emulation hooked up you could take advantage of that to provide a different background shade for vim with more subtle gradiation than "black" vs "grey".  This is sort of complicated, but there are howtos somewhere or other.  IIRC most modern terminal emulators support 256-color mode, and I think the same is true of most builds of vim (there's a compilation option that needs to be enabled).

Answer (score 4):

Gnome's and KDE's terminal emulators have an option for background images, and they have "profiles" that can set up different settings for different usage.  You should be able to set up a 'vim' profile in one of these with its own background image pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Can GVIM have a background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753082/can-gvim-have-a-background-image) I assume it's not possible. Why would you even want this?

Comment: I feel, if I add the background image it will differentiate konsole, terminal, and vim files.

Comment: Why isn't setting the background color enough for this differentation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117526/vim-background is a possibility in that case. And is there a reason to use `vim` instead of `gvim` which has more possibilities for costumization?

Comment: I prefer `vim` because I can locate it within two more levels of organization, ie within a `screen` session within a terminal tab.  There might be others, I really don't use `gvim` because losing that alone blows the sale.  Also the fact that if X crashes my vim session is still alive is pretty nice.